# How to change the edittext value in changing the activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, expandablelistview

Suppose there too much Expandablelistview in which many of Expandablelistview Group is having Edittext and Button and some don't have which Group is not having the Edittext  and Button there Child is having the Edittext and Button. In Click of Button I am changing the Activity with passing the edittext value with it.

In another Activity I am change the value of it and when I am moving back to that activity the particular that Edittext value should change.

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ExpandableChild child = (ExpandableChild) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl);
    viewHolder.rl1 = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl1);

    if (child.getCurcod() == null) {
        viewHolder.rl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        viewHolder.rl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        viewHolder.mod = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);

        viewHolder.mod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent fgj = new Intent(context, TwoActivity.class);
                    fgj.putExtra("child", "child");
                    fgj.putExtra("grouppos",groupPosition);
                    fgj.putExtra("childpos",childPosition);
                    fgj.putExtra("qty", viewHolder.editText.getText().toString());
                    context.startActivity(fgj);
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ExpandableGroup group = (ExpandableGroup) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    viewHolder.rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl);
    viewHolder.rl1 = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rl1);

    if (group.getCurcod() == null) {
        viewHolder.rl1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.itemNameGrp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemGrp);

        viewHolder.itemNameGrp.setText(group.getItmnam());

    } else {
        viewHolder.rl1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        viewHolder.rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        viewHolder.editText = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        viewHolder.mod = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView14);

        viewHolder.mod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (viewHolder.editText.getText().toString().equals("0") || viewHolder.editText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Quantity cannot be empty or Zero", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Intent fgj = new Intent(context, TwoActivity.class);
                    fgj.putExtra("child", "group");
                    fgj.putExtra("grouppos",groupPosition);
                    fgj.putExtra("childpos",0);
                    fgj.putExtra("qty", viewHolder.editText.getText().toString());
                    context.startActivity(fgj);
                }
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```

Even one more problem is coming when I enter some value in edittext box and scroll the page the value get change or get place in another edittext box

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preferences to add/Update the values !!